# Microsoft bot application template is not visible in Visual studio 2017. How to add bot application template?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, botframework

Microsoft bot application template is not visible in Visual studio 2017. How to add bot application template in Visual studio. Is this possible to add template with Visual studio installer or i need to add with Add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

karna, you can get a VSIX installer from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4)

Comment: Just to add on to this, in case you were wondering how to use the vsix, you can add it to your `Visual Studio 2017/Templates/ProjectTemplates/` as a .zip file to use in Visual studio. It will show up automatically in your list of templates.

Comment: Thank you Ed Boykin. I have installed Bot Builder V4 SDK Template for Visual Studio with the link you shared. I dont see bot application in templates, I can see only Bot builder V4 SDK templates. This Bot builder SDK will work same as Bot application?

Comment: You are all set. The SDK templates are just newer templates versus the older bot application templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for BotFramework V3 Project Template it is no longer available on visual studio marketplace.

However, you can download from my github repo instead:

It comes with a custom state storage. It's Entity Framework based.

Download Link: https://github.com/rcarubbi/EchoBotV3LocalDBTemplate/releases/download/1.0/Bot.Builder.Echo.Bot.V3.with.LocalDB.State.zip

Source Code: https://github.com/rcarubbi/EchoBotV3LocalDBTemplate